# logback maxHistory does not work , history is deleted

Tags: logging, logback

I'm facing a situation with logback , its supposed to keep history accoding to the  tag

this is my appender configuration

```
<appender name="LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/logs/pglogger.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- rollover daily -->
      <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/pglogger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
       <!-- each file should be at most 100MB, keep 60 days worth of history, but at most 20GB -->
       <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>    
       <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
       <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```

but logback only keeps one day history, it always deletes other old log files
we restart servers every day at the same time ,i dont know if it can have side effects.

im using the 1.3.5 of logback with slf4j 2.0.6.

Thanks .

i changed the maxHistory unit to hours , i put 720 (24*30) but it does not have any effect